# C++ Named Return Value Optimization with nested function calls

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that NRVO allows a function to construct an object and return that object by value without the cost of a copy or even move operation. It found that it also works with nested function calls, allowing you to construct the object from the return value of another function call.

Please consider the following program and it's output as shown in the comments:
(Output from Visual Studio 2017, version 15.2, release build.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
class W
{
public:
  W() { printf( "W::W()\n" ); }
  W( const W& ) { printf( "W::W( const W& )\n" ); }
  W( W&& ) { printf( "W::W( W&& )\n" ); }
  W& operator=( const W& ) { printf( "W::operator=( const W& )\n" ); }
  W& operator=( W&& ) { printf( "W::operator=( W&& )\n" ); }
  ~W() { printf( "W::~W()\n" ); }
  void Transform() { printf( "W::Transform()\n" ); }
  void Run() { printf( "W::Run()\n" ); }
};

W make()
{
  W w;
  return w;
}

W transform_make()
{
  W w{ make() };
  w.Transform();
  return w;
}

W transform1( W w )
{
  w.Transform();
  return w;
}

W&& transform2( W&& w )
{
  w.Transform();
  return std::move(w);
}

int main()                         // Program output:
{
  printf( "TestM:\n" );            //TestM:
  {                                //W::W()
    W w{ make() };                 //W::Run()
    w.Run();                       //W::~W()
  }
                                   //TestTM:
  printf( "TestTM:\n" );           //W::W()
  {                                //W::Transform()
    W w{ transform_make() };       //W::Run()
    w.Run();                       //W::~W()
  }
                                   //TestT1:
  printf( "TestT1:\n" );           //W::W()
  {                                //W::Transform()
    W w{ transform1( make() ) };   //W::W( W&& )
    w.Run();                       //W::~W()
  }                                //W::Run()
                                   //W::~W()

  printf( "TestT2:\n" );           //TestT2:
  {                                //W::W()
    W&& w{ transform2( make() ) }; //W::Transform()
    w.Run();                       //W::~W()
  }                                //W::Run()
}
```

`TestM` is the normal NRVO case. The object `W` is constructed and destructed only once.
`TestTM` is the nested NRVO case. Again the object is constructed only once and never copied or moved. So far so good.

Now getting to my question - how can I make `TestT1` work with the same efficiency as `TestTM`? As you can see in `TestT1` a second object is move constructed - this is something I would like to avoid. How can I change the function `transform1()` to avoid any additional copies or moves? If you think about it, `TestT1` is not that much different from `TestTM`, so I have a feeling that this is something that must be possible.

For my second attempt, `TestT2`, I tried passing the object via RValue reference. This eliminated the extra move constructor, but unfortunately this causes the destructor to be called before I am done with the object, which is not always ideal.

**Update:**
I also note that it is possible to make it work using references, as long as you make sure not to use the object beyond the end of the statement:

```
W&& transform2( W&& w )
{
  w.Transform();
  return std::move(w);
}

void run( W&& w )
{
  w.Run();
}

printf( "TestT3:\n" );           //TestT3:
{                                //W::W()
  run( transform2( make() ) );   //W::Transform()
}                                //W::Run()
                                 //W::~W()
```

Is this safe to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in `Test1` because the compiler is explicitly disallowed to apply NRVO from by value parameters from a function's argument list.  And in `Test1` you are accepting a `W` instance by value as a function parameter, so the compiler cannot elide the move on return.

See [Why are by-value parameters excluded from NRVO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009278/why-are-by-value-parameters-excluded-from-nrvo) and my discussion with Howard Hinnant about the issue here [Why does for_each return function by move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163801/why-does-for-each-return-function-by-move) in the comments

You cannot make `Test1` work as efficiently as you did in the earlier case because of this.

---

The relevant quote from the standard

**15.8.3 Copy/move elision [class.copy.elision]**

> 1. When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, ...
>
>    - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the *expression* is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function parameter or a variable introduced by the *exception-declaration* of a *handler* (18.3)) with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function call’s return object

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. But why does `TestT2` not work? I thought the reference would have extended the lifetime of the temporary object?

Comment: @Barnett the lifetime of the object bound to a reference is only extended if the object that is being bound is a complete object (for most purposes, if its a prvalue) or a complete subobject of a complete object (for example `auto&& val = Something{}.member_variable`).  And temporaries that do not have their lifetime extended last for the entirety of the expression they appear in.  So your `&&` parameters and return values in the `TestT2` don't extend the lifetime of any temporaries bound beyond the lifetime of the expression the function call appears in

Comment: Also see both the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441791/lifetime-extension-prvalues-and-xvalues, they might help in explaining things a bit more

Comment: @Curious  can the object be somehow passed through a method in a way such as guaranteed RVO is preserved (i.e. prvalue materialization is avoided)?